# Is performance debugging in React Native using React Dev Tools Profiler valid since it requires DEV mode === true?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-chrome-devtools, react-devtools, react-native-debugger

In the React Native profiling docs it says:

> make sure that Development Mode is OFF! JavaScript thread performance suffers greatly when running in dev mode. This is unavoidable: a lot more work needs to be done at runtime to provide you with good warnings and error messages, such as validating propTypes and various other assertions. Always make sure to test performance in release builds.

However development mode needs to be on to use React Native Debugger and its Profiler.

So is it a good method of obtaining performance information? If the results are consistent then can they be a reliable way to measure performance?